# Stop MdiChild form roaming inside Parent container on Form Load

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, mdi

Every time I re-open a form inside an `MdiParent` Container, the child form moves a small amount (~20 pixels) down and towards the right.

Is there a way to stop the form from doing this on form load, without stopping it from being moved freely within the parent?

Here is an example:

[image]

and then reload the child form:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `StartPosition` property on the child form:

```
StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
```

The default value is `WindowsDefaultLocation`, which causes each instance of the child form to drift down and to the right each time.

---

The following block of code from the `Form` class is called when the form is an `MdiChild` form, and the form is initially being displayed. *(I trimmed out some unrelated parts.)*

For all other `StartPosition` values beside `Manual`, there's some calculation going on regarding the location of the form, but it does nothing for `StartPosition.Manual`.

```
 // Adjusts the CreateParams to reflect the window bounds and start position.
 private void FillInCreateParamsStartPosition(CreateParams cp) { 
    switch ((FormStartPosition)formState[FormStateStartPos]) {
        case FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultBounds: 
            cp.Width = NativeMethods.CW_USEDEFAULT;
            cp.Height = NativeMethods.CW_USEDEFAULT; 
            ...
        case FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultLocation: 
        case FormStartPosition.CenterParent:
            ...
            cp.X = NativeMethods.CW_USEDEFAULT;
            cp.Y = NativeMethods.CW_USEDEFAULT;
            break;
        case FormStartPosition.CenterScreen: 
            if (IsMdiChild) {
                ...
                cp.X = Math.Max(clientRect.X,clientRect.X + (clientRect.Width - cp.Width)/2); 
                cp.Y = Math.Max(clientRect.Y,clientRect.Y + (clientRect.Height - cp.Height)/2);
            }
            else {
                ...
                if (WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized) { 
                    cp.X = Math.Max(screenRect.X,screenRect.X + (screenRect.Width - cp.Width)/2); 
                    cp.Y = Math.Max(screenRect.Y,screenRect.Y + (screenRect.Height - cp.Height)/2);
                } 
            }
            break;
    }
}
```